# Ajax shows no response where server returns result

Tags: php, ajax

Ajax send [GET](http://questionbank.freevar.com/site/agent_manager_response.php?cmd=fsave&id=1&phone=25411577856&account_active=1&fname=shantanu&lname=saha&time_zone=2&street=asdf%20lsjdf&suite=asdf&ring=0&city=dhaka&state=bangladesh&zip=52145&call_time=110&call_length=2.50&call_count=152) request to server. Also server return success result.

```
Server response:
[{"result":"success"}]
```

But ajax does not shows any responseText. Firebug shows the get request with red color.
[image]

Ajax code section:

```
var params = "&id=" +id + "&phone="+phone + "&account_active=" + activeAccount + "&fname="+fname + "&lname="+lname + "&time_zone="+timezone + "&street="+street+"&suite="+suite+"&ring="+ring+"&city="+city+"&state="+state +"&zip="+zip+"&call_time="+callTime +"&call_length="+callLength+"&call_count="+callCount;  
    
var xmlhttp = getXMLObject();
xmlhttp.open("GET",'agent_manager_response.php?cmd=fsave'+params,true);
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
   if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
    var data = eval(xmlhttp.responseText);
       if(data[0].result == "success"){
        alert('Successfully saved');
       }
      else{
        alert("Error saving data\nError: " + data[0].result);
      }
    }
}
xmlhttp.send(null);
```

Server code:

```
$result = mysql_query($query,$con);
$data=array();
if(!$result)
     array_push($data,array('result'=>mysql_error()));
else
     array_push($data,array('result'=>'success'));
        
echo json_encode($data);
```

Ajax response DOM tab(from firebug)

```
DONE 4  
HEADERS_RECEIVED  2
LOADING  3
OPENED   1
UNSENT   0
getchannel  undefined
mozBackgroundRequest  false
multipart    false
onloadend   null
onuploadprogress  null
readyState    4
response     ""
responseText   ""
responseType   ""
responseXML   null
status      0
getstatusText  ""
getupload    undefined
withCredentials   false
abort    abort()
addEventListener  addEventListener()
dispatchEvent   dispatchEvent()
getAllResponseHeaders   getAllResponseHeaders()
getInterface    getInterface()
getResponseHeader   getResponseHeader()
open   open()
overrideMimeType    overrideMimeType()
removeEventListener removeEventListener()
send      send()
sendAsBinary  sendAsBinary()
setRequestHeader   setRequestHeader()
```

Net tab status:
[image]

## EDITED

This is all i have in net tab:
[image]

Comment: Check the `Net` tab and check the exact http response headers

Comment: @Jack thanks for quick reply. i have added net tab status. I forgot to mention one thing, after that call full page reload instead of reload a section.

Comment: You've made a screenshot of the Net tab, but of the wrong request; the request to the .php is what I'm after.

Comment: Make sure that your server sets the correct Content-Type. Right now it sends `text/html` but you are returning `application/json`. So fix your PHP script.

Answer (score 0):

Add Content Type:

```
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
```

And Change:

```
var data = eval(xmlhttp.responseText);
```

to

```
var data = eval( '(' + xmlhttp.responseText + ')' );
```